# Codeigniter - Can "foo" subdomain automatically use controllers in "foo" folder?

Tags: codeigniter, subdomain, subdirectory, wildcard-subdomain

As is usual with Codeigniter, assuming I have `$route['default_controller'] = "welcome";`, if I request the url on the left, I am using the controllers listed on the right:

```
www.foo.com/         =>  applications/controllers/welcome.php with method "index"
www.foo.com/bar      =>  applications/controllers/bar.php with method "index"
www.foo.com/bar/baz  =>  applications/controllers/bar.php with method "baz"
```

This is all as expected. But when a subdomain is used, I would like to have codeigniter **use controllers in a subdirectory with the same name as the subdomain:**

```
abc.foo.com/         =>  app/controllers/abc/welcome.php with method "index"
abc.foo.com/baz      =>  app/controllers/abc/baz.php with method "index"
abc.foo.com/baz/qux  =>  app/controllers/abc/baz.php with method "qux"
```

Can this be done with routes? If so, how do you set routes based on subdomain?

Or is there a simpler way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check for subdomains in routes.php file like:

```
if (strstr($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], 'abc.foo.com')) {
   $route['uri'] = "abc/controller/method";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible,

`$route['the/path'] = "folder/controller/method";`